# NCalc on Windows Phone (Silverlight)

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8

Is there a way to use Ncalc on a windows phone 8 project? If not are there any alternatives to use?

I added it to my project through nuget but when i try to evaluate an expression it throws an exception

> A first chance exception of type 'NCalc.EvaluationException' occurred in NCalc.DLL
>       Could not load type 'System.Threading.ReaderWriterLock' from assembly 'mscorlib

Comment: [FLEE](http://flee.codeplex.com/) has a [Silverlight compatible version](http://flee.codeplex.com/workitem/8121) that I've used successfully on Silverlight and Xamarin.Android. I haven't tried it for Windows Phone _specifically_, so I'm not sure if it would work or not. It uses the `System.Reflection.Emit` namespace to emit IL instructions; this may not be compatible for Windows Phone and/or Windows Store App licensing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [Jace.Net](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/682589/Jace-NET-Just-Another-Calculation-Engine-for-NET) it works perfectly with WP8.